# How to convert a C++ class into a .NET object?

Tags: c#, .net, c++builder-10.1-berlin

We have a C# programmer that wants a .NET object to do all the underlying work. It should basically be a black box with functions and events.

I had written all this with C++ Builder, using non-visual VCL classes and now it seems like I have to make a .NET object out of it.

I need a simple example of how to create a .NET "box" with one function and one event handler and from there I should be able to implement the rest of it. Should I do this in a COM object? What technology should I use?

Example C++ side.

```
typedef void __fastcall (__closure *TIntEvent)(int Status);
typedef void __fastcall (__closure *TVoidEvent)(void);
typedef void __fastcall (__closure *TResultEvent)(String cmd, int code);
typedef void __fastcall (__closure *TModeEvent)(int mode, int reason);

class TDevice : public TObject {

    private:
        // properties
        String FPortName;
        String FDevice;
        String FComment;
        String FID;
        double FBootware;
        double FFirmware;

    protected:

    public:
        // properties
        __property String PortName     = { read=FPortName     };
        __property String Device       = { read=FDevice       };
        __property String Comment      = { read=FComment      };
        __property String ID           = { read=FID           };
        __property double Bootware     = { read=FBootware     };
        __property double Firmware     = { read=FFirmware     };

        // event function pointers
        TModeEvent   OnMode;
        TIntEvent    OnStatus;
        TIntEvent    OnSensors;
        TVoidEvent   OnInfo;
        TResultEvent OnResult;

       // public interface
       bool Connect(void);
       void Disconnect(void);

       void Reset(void);
       void Boot(void);
       void GetInfo(void);
       void GetTag(void);
};
```

I have removed all the internal stuff and only left exposed functions, events and properties that should be possible to reach from C#.

From this class I need to create a .NET object like this:

```
MyLib.IDevice.Connect();
MyLib.IDevice.Disconnect();
MyLib.IDevice.Reset();
MyLib.IDevice.Boot();
MyLib.IDevice.GetInfo();
MyLib.IDevice.GetTag();
```

I also need C# to connect a function to the Event handlers in the C++ class.

```
MyLib.IDevice.OnMode    = CSharpEventHandler1;
MyLib.IDevice.OnStatus  = CSharpEventHandler2;
MyLib.IDevice.OnSensors = CSharpEventHandler3;
MyLib.IDevice.OnInfo    = CSharpEventHandler4;
MyLib.IDevice.OnResult  = CSharpEventHandler5;
```

These event handlers are called inside the C++ class to fire the events like this:

```
if(OnMode != NULL)
{
  OnMode(FMode,FReason);
}
```

There are also a few properties, but these are easy to impalement in a COM interface (if this is what we need)...

Since this is written in C++ Builder and C++ builder can write components (for C++ Builder and Delphi, using ActiveX technology), maybe it is possible to convert a C++ Builder component library into a .Net object/component?

EDIT:
To make it even more clear...

The MyLib.IDevice.Connect() is what I want C# to see... The list of functions are the C++ functions as in a .Net object MyLib with an interface IDevice.

So assuming I have created an instance of MyLib.IDevice as Device, I can call Device.Connect(); from C#.

Comment: Use c++/CLI or COM

Comment: @MickyD He probably can't... He is already using a "different" C++ (C++Builder)... So even Microsoft C++/CLI can't "connect" to the C++Builder class (that is derived from `TObject`)

Comment: @max Your question is unclear: *From this class I need to create a .NET object like this: `MyLib.IDevice.Connect();`* You aren't creating an object... You are calling a method (`Connect`) from a static object (`IDevice`).

Comment: My suggestion is that you create a `export "C" { }` C-language interface to your class. From that it is probably easy to create C# pinvokes

Comment: @xanatos The MyLib.IDevice.Connect() is what I want C# to see... The list is the C++ functions as in a .Net object MyLib with an interface IDevice.

Comment: I know how to do a COM object (if this is the right path to go), but the problem is how to define the event handlers and fire them from the C++ side. C++ Builder = unmanaged code, C# = Managed code.

Answer (score 3):

It is hard... And ugly... The simplest solution is probably to create a C interface:

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall TDevice* NewDevice()
    {
        return new TDevice();
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall DeleteDevice(TDevice *pDevice)
    {
        delete pDevice;
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) bool __stdcall ConnectDevice(TDevice *pDevice)
    {
        return pDevice->Connect();
    }

    .. and so on
}
```

In C#:

```
[DllImport("YourDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Stdcall)]
public static extern IntPtr NewDevice();

[DllImport("YourDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Stdcall)]
public static extern void DeleteDevice(IntPtr pDevice);

[DllImport("YourDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Stdcall)]
public static extern bool ConnectDevice(IntPtr pDevice);

... and so on
```

If you are ok with this, we can begin talking about passing delegates... and it will be a pain, trust me :-)

Uff... It was quite long... C++ side it is better if you create a wrapper for your class. This because you are using `__fastcall __closure` for your events. Both of these modifiers are incompatible with C#, so you "proxy" them in the wrapper.

```
// __fastcall not handled by C#
typedef void __stdcall (*TIntEventFunc)(int Status);
typedef void __stdcall (*TVoidEventFunc)(void);
typedef void __stdcall (*TResultEventFunc)(const wchar_t *cmd, int code);
typedef void __stdcall (*TModeEventFunc)(int mode, int reason);

class TDeviceWrapper {
    public:
        // You could even use directly a TDevice Device, depending on how your program works.
        // By using a TDevice *, you can attach the wrapper to a preexisting TDevice.
        TDevice *PDevice;

        TModeEventFunc      OnModeFunc;
        TIntEventFunc       OnStatusFunc;
        TIntEventFunc       OnSensorsFunc;
        TVoidEventFunc      OnInfoFunc;
        TResultEventFunc    OnResultFunc;

        void __fastcall OnStatus(int status) {
            OnStatusFunc(status);
        }

        void __fastcall OnResult(String cmd, int code)
        {
            OnResultFunc(cmd.c_str(), code);
        }
};

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) TDeviceWrapper* __stdcall NewDevice()
    {
        auto pWrapper = new TDeviceWrapper();
        pWrapper->PDevice = new TDevice();
        return pWrapper;
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall DeleteDevice(TDeviceWrapper *pWrapper)
    {
        delete pWrapper->PDevice;
        delete pWrapper;
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) const wchar_t* __stdcall GetPortName(TDeviceWrapper *pWrapper)
    {
        return pWrapper->PDevice->PortName.c_str();
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) bool __stdcall Connect(TDeviceWrapper *pWrapper)
    {
        return pWrapper->PDevice->Connect();
    }   

    __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall SetStatus(TDeviceWrapper *pWrapper, TIntEventFunc statusFunc) {
        pWrapper->OnStatusFunc = statusFunc;

        if (statusFunc) {
            pWrapper->PDevice->OnStatus = pWrapper->OnStatus;
        } else {
            pWrapper->PDevice->OnStatus = nullptr;
        }
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall SetResult(TDeviceWrapper *pWrapper, TResultEventFunc resultFunc) {
        pWrapper->OnResultFunc = resultFunc;

        if (resultFunc) {
            pWrapper->PDevice->OnResult = pWrapper->OnResult;
        } else {
            pWrapper->PDevice->OnResult = nullptr;
        }
    }
}
```

Then C#-side you have to create *another* wrapper :-) This time because when you pass a delegate C#->C++, the .NET creates a "thunk", but if you don't save the delegate somewhere, this "thunk" gets garbage collected. So the easiest solution is normally to create a wrapper class where you can save the used delegates. You can even incapsulate the `Dispose()` pattern in this wrapper :-)

```
public class TDeviceWrapper : IDisposable
{
    // Fastcall not handled by C#
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public delegate void TIntEventFunc(int Status);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public delegate void TVoidEventFunc();

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public delegate void TResultEventFunc(string cmd, int code);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public delegate void TModeEventFunc(int mode, int reason);

    IntPtr ptr;

    [DllImport("TDevice.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr NewDevice();

    [DllImport("TDevice.dll")]
    static extern void DeleteDevice(IntPtr pWrapper);

    [DllImport("TDevice.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetPortName(IntPtr pWrapper);

    [DllImport("TDevice.dll")]
    static extern void Connect(IntPtr pWrapper);

    [DllImport("TDevice.dll")]
    static extern void SetStatus(IntPtr pWrapper, TIntEventFunc statusFunc);

    [DllImport("TDevice.dll")]
    static extern void SetResult(IntPtr pWrapper, TResultEventFunc resultFunc);

    // To prevent the GC from collecting the managed-tounmanaged thunks, we save the delegates
    TModeEventFunc modeFunc;
    TIntEventFunc statusFunc;
    TIntEventFunc sensorsFunc;
    TVoidEventFunc infoFunc;
    TResultEventFunc resultFunc;

    public void Init()
    {
        ptr = NewDevice();
    }

    public string PortName
    {
        get
        {
            // Important! .NET will try to free the returned
            // string if GetPortName returns directly a string.
            // See for example https://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/returning-strings-from-a-c-api/
            IntPtr ptr2 = GetPortName(ptr);
            return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ptr2);
        }
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        Connect(ptr);
    }

    public void SetStatus(TIntEventFunc statusFunc)
    {
        this.statusFunc = statusFunc;
        SetStatus(ptr, statusFunc);
    }

    public void SetResult(TResultEventFunc resultFunc)
    {
        this.resultFunc = resultFunc;
        SetResult(ptr, resultFunc);
    }

    ~TDeviceWrapper()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            DeleteDevice(ptr);
            ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        if (disposing)
        {
            modeFunc = null;
            statusFunc = null;
            sensorsFunc = null;
            infoFunc = null;
            resultFunc = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can, for example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void StatusEvent(int status)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", status);
    }

    public void ResultEvent(string cmd, int code)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Resukt: {0}, {1}", cmd, code);
    }
}
```

and

```
var mc = new MyClass();

using (var wrapper = new TDeviceWrapper())
{
    wrapper.Init();
    wrapper.SetStatus(mc.StatusEvent);
    wrapper.SetResult(mc.ResultEvent);
    wrapper.Connect();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, if this is the way to do it I guess there is no other choice. I guess I can write a C# class wrapping the dll imports to make it look like a "real" C# object.

Comment: @MaxKielland Note that for delegates it will be a pain... this because you can't use `__closure` pointers in C#. C# callbacks must be "global" funcions (or static methods of a class).

Comment: @MaxKielland And just keeping a C# delegate "alive" (protected from the Garbage Collector) is already a pain...

Comment: @MaxKielland I've written a complete example. It is working, and I know it because I've downloaded the free version of bcc32 and tested the generated dll :-) With this I do mean that if you forget a `CallingConvention.StdCall` somewhere, first you try *very hard* to find your error, then you ask me for an help.

Comment: @MaxKielland Fixed the .NET code (`PortName`/`GetPortName`)... I hate pinvoke :-)

Comment: Thank you a lot. I will try it out in a few days, I have to go out of office on a trip tomorrow.